# how to Load PPT in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I need to prepare proof-of-concept for a silverlight application. For that I need to load PPT in silverlight. I just need to load PPT in browser and allow the user to perform next, previous, stop and pause actions. Anybody can help out.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you need to convert the powerpoint slides to images first? then build a "player" in silverlight to show these slides?

Not sure if Office supports export to Images? (for a manual process) but you could print to PostScript and convert to images using GhostScript.

Comment: Silverlight may only have the capabilities to load images, therefore you will need to get the slides into a format that Silverlight can load, I did give a couple of suggestions to how you can convert powerpoint slides to images. You will need to investigate the best solution for your development and hosting environment and ultimately do the actual work yourself.